# Listing files from ftp using spring-integration

Tags: java, ftp, spring-integration

I want to list all of files on an FTP server using spring-integration and, for example, print them on screen. I've done something like this:

context:

```
<int:channel id="toSplitter">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" log-full-message="true"/>
<int:splitter id="splitter" input-channel="toSplitter" output-channel="getFtpChannel"/>

<int-ftp:outbound-gateway id="gatewayLS"
                        session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
                        request-channel="inbound"
                        command="ls"
                        expression="payload"
                        reply-channel="toSplitter"/>
<int:channel id="getFtpChannel">
    <int:queue/>
</int:channel>
    <bean id="ftpClientFactory"
        class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="${host}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
    <property name="clientMode" value="0"/>
    <property name="fileType" value="2"/>
    <property name="bufferSize" value="10000000"/>                  
</bean>
```

Java code:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = 
            new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/src/citrus/resources/citrus-context.xml");
final FtpFlowGateway ftpFlow = context.getBean(FtpFlowGateway.class);
ftpFlow.lsFiles("/");
PollableChannel channel = context.getBean("getFtpChannel", PollableChannel.class);
variable("tt", channel.receive().toString());
echo("${tt}");
```

output:

```
11:09:17,169 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| Test action <echo>
11:09:17,169 INFO    actions.EchoAction| [Payload=FileInfo [isDirectory=false,  isLink=false, Size=3607, ModifiedTime=Tue Jul 15 14:18:00 CEST 2014,       Filename=Smoke03_angart30_st40.exi, RemoteDirectory=/, Permiss
ions=-rw-r--r--]][Headers= {replyChannel=org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@7829b776, sequenceNumber=1,  errorChannel=org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTempla
te$TemporaryReplyChannel@7829b776, file_remoteDirectory=/, sequenceSize=1, correlationId=49b57f2d-4dbf-4a89-b5b8-0dfb15bca2be, id=0a58ad65-74b4-4aae-87be- aa6034a41776, timestamp=1405501757060}]
11:09:17,169 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| Test action <echo> done
11:09:17,169 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| TEST STEP 1/1 done
```

The output is fine, but what should I do to print this information when I don't know how many files are stored on the FTP? (this code prints only one file). I've tried checking if `channel.receive()` is null but the test just freezes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you send the result of `LS` to the `<splitter>`, your `getFtpChannel` will receive `FileInfo<?>` objects one by one.

To print them all you really should have an infinite loop:

```
while (true) {
  variable("tt", channel.receive().toString());
  echo("${tt}");
}
```

To stop the app you should provide some `shoutDownHook` or listen something from console input.

Another point, that it is bad to block your app with infinite `receive()`.
There is na overloaded method, which applies a `timeout` param. The last one might be useful to determine the end of your loop:

```
while (true) {
  Message<?> receive = channel.receive(10000);
  if (receive == null) {
      break;
  }
  variable("tt", receive.toString());
  echo("${tt}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Configuration
public class FtpConfig {

    @Bean
    public DefaultFtpSessionFactory ftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultFtpSessionFactory ftpSessionFactory = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
        ftpSessionFactory.setHost("localhost");
        ftpSessionFactory.setPort(21);
        ftpSessionFactory.setUsername("user");
        ftpSessionFactory.setPassword("pass");
        return ftpSessionFactory;
    }

}
```

```java
@Bean
public ApplicationRunner runner(DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf) {
   return args -> {
       FTPFile[] list = sf.getSession().list(".");
       for (FTPFile file: list ) {
           System.out.println("Result: " + file.getName());
       }
   };
}
```

Comment: Please explain what this wall of text does. As far as the uninitiated are concerned it might teach the OP to shout 'Fus Ro Dah'

Comment: This is the easiest way to get a list of files from sftp. In case you only need to print this list on the screen.